# How to go back to default GCC version of Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gcc

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04) 10.1.0


$ type -a gcc
gcc is /usr/bin/gcc


$ update-alternatives --query gcc
Name: gcc
Link: /usr/bin/gcc
Slaves:
 g++ /usr/bin/g++
Status: auto
Best: /usr/bin/gcc-10
Value: /usr/bin/gcc-10

Alternative: /usr/bin/gcc-10
Priority: 60
Slaves:
 g++ /usr/bin/g++-10
```

I don't exactly remember what steps I followed to get to this version.

I want to uninstall the new gcc and have just the old one back.
Please help me to revert back to default version on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: there is a .deb at this link for 18.04 (https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/gcc-7-base_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb.html)

Comment: Please help us to help you by [edit]ing your question to include the outputs of `type -a gcc`, `update-alternatives --query gcc` and `ls -l "$(which gcc)"`

Comment: @steeldriver have edited the question.